# How to serialize/deserialize an individual (stand alone) repeated field in Protocol buffers?

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers, proto

```
message X
{
  bool b = 1;
  repeated string s = 2;
  // other fields
}
```

I have a requirement to individually store the field `repeated X::s` in a serialized form in a DB or text. However I am unable to find any `SerializeAsString()` method for repeated fields.

A slightly cumbersome workaround is to wrap the `repeated` field inside another message:

```
message S { repeated string array = 1; }
message X
{
  bool b = 1;
  S s = 2;
  // other fields
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: There's no way to do that. You have to wrap it into a message.